# IE11 Always allow session cookies workaround

Tags: php, session, internet-explorer-11

I've found a lot of articles on this subject, but no workarounds for my case.

All of my websites are PHP based and I often use `$_SESSION['some_session']='some_value'` etc. in my code.

In this case I am setting a session to register if a visitor has been on a particular page. As soon as this session is set, the visitor's navigation is extended to include additional pages.

This works fine on all browsers except IE11. It seems that the default privacy setting `'Always allow session cookies'` being turned to off is causing the problem. As soon as I turn this on, the session and extended navigation works.

1. Can I somehow force IE11 to accept my session even when the privacy setting is turned to off?
2. Is there a workaround using some other form of session?
3. Is there a workaround using something other than sessions which isn't going to make me overhaul all my scripts?

Many thanks in advance!